# Google Cloud Messaging with PhoneGap

Tags: android, cordova, cloud

I am trying to add Google Cloud Messaging in my android app using PhoneGap. I was following this plugin https://github.com/marknutter/GCM-Cordova

Unfortunately, the steps are not very clear. When i try to follow step: "Add the GCMIntentService.java file to your application's main package." i ended up with many errors, there are other file references in this file too.

Is there any tutorial or other plugin available?

Thank you

Answer (score 4):

If you want push notifications I recommend you to use PushWoosh because I've been using it and goes really well. 
As you don't show the exact errors of inserting GCMIntentService.java I only can guess that maybe you're not putting the source in the correct package or your Cordova version is not the needed for that plugin. Check your version and if it isn't this try to click in Eclipse the Fix Tool or Clean the project.
Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I tried PushWoosh but it is not sending notifications. Don't see any device subscribed in the  PushWoosh Control Panel. I tried their sample app; not working either. With sample app i can at least see it subscribed in the CP but not receiving notifications.

Comment: Remember that the sample app you've downloaded needs to subscribe to Google API, so you need your API key. (http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gs.html) Read Pushwoosh tutorial to see where to put your project ID and API key in your project. You also need at least that your Cordova library to be 1.9 version